# A question on differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following second order differential equation:

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + \frac{2v +1}{t} \frac{dy}{dt} + y = 0, v \in \mathbb{R} $$

If this has a solution $y(t)$ that is smooth on an interval about $0$. Show that $y(-t)$ is also a solution.

My obstacle is I do not know how to use smoothness of $y$ to get started.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: so it means that   v is constant right?i mean it is some number

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53882/does-the-solution-of-any-differential-equation-without-boundary-conditions-is

Comment: it is also interesting it's solution,what would be characteristic equation of this model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z(t) = y(\tau)$, where $\tau = -t$. We then have
$$\dfrac{dz(t)}{dt} = \dfrac{dy(\tau)}{d \tau} \cdot \dfrac{d \tau}{dt} = - \dfrac{dy(\tau)}{d \tau} \,\,\, (\spadesuit)$$
$$\dfrac{d^2z(t)}{dt^2} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\left(- \dfrac{dy(\tau)}{d \tau} \right) = -\dfrac{d}{d \tau}\left(\dfrac{dy(\tau)}{d \tau}\right) \dfrac{d \tau}{dt} = \dfrac{d^2 y(\tau)}{d \tau^2} \,\,\, (\clubsuit)$$
We have that $y(\tau)$ satisfies
$$\dfrac{d^2 y(\tau)}{d \tau^2} + \dfrac{2v+1}{\tau} \dfrac{d y(\tau)}{d \tau} + y(\tau) = 0$$
Making use of $(\spadesuit)$ and $(\clubsuit)$, we now get
$$\dfrac{d^2 z(t)}{d t^2} + \dfrac{2v+1}{(-t)} \left(-\dfrac{d z(t)}{d t} \right) + z(t) = 0$$
which gives us
$$\dfrac{d^2 z(t)}{d t^2} + \dfrac{2v+1}{t} \dfrac{d z(t)}{d t} + z(t) = 0$$